# ¿Cómo mostrar OpenJPA SQL usando logback y slf4j?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, openjpa

En nuestro proyecto usamos logback y slf4j para mostrar los LOG por Consola y para guardarlos en archivos log, todo configurado en nuestro logback.xml, algo que ya hemos implementado de forma satisfactoria.

Ahora queremos incluir las llamadas SQL con JPA, tal y cómo se haría en log4j (vamos, el equivalente a "*log4j.category.openjpa.jdbc.SQL=TRACE*"), pero la solución oficial de Logback es usar las librerías de Codehaus(https://www.codehaus.org/)... cuyos servicios han terminado.

¿Existe alguna alternativa actual, para el OpenJPA, sin dejar de usar las librerías logback? No es un proyecto con Maven, y no busco de momento como implementar otras opciones alternativas como podría ser utilizar OpenEJB.

Comment: Pero si no usas maven, ¿Qué problema te da bajar unos jars y alojarlos en tu proyecto?

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. Si utilizas slf4j, él proveerá una fachada para cualquiera que sea la librería de log que utiliza el proyecto y lo delegará a logback. Solo deberías configurar en tu logback.xml (o como lo tengas) el paquete que quieres logear y su nivel de log.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te comenta *@Luiggi* es tu solución, **Slf4j es una fachada** con la que tu trabajas en tu código, pero debes proveer la implementación según el sistema de log que estés utilizando.

[Aquí puedes ver los binding de Slf4j y los los frameworks de log que soporta](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping)

Answer (score 0):

Según una pregunta equivalente [del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733408/how-do-i-configure-openjpa-sql-logging):

```
openjpa.Log=SQL=Trace
openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties.PrintParameters=true
log4j.category.openjpa.jdbc.SQL=TRACE
log4j.category.openjpa.Query=TRACE
```

Adicionalmente podrías revisar la [documentación](https://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual.html#ref_guide_logging) al respecto.